# Problem in calling an Ethereum contract method using Web3.php

Tags: web3.php

I am using Web3.php to read an ERC20 token balance of a wallet from its contract.

```
use Web3\Web3;
use Web3\Contract;
use Web3\Utils;
$web3 = new Web3('https://node.surnet.org:8545');
$contractAbi = file_get_contents("abi.json");
$contractAddress = "0x...";
$contract = new Contract($web3->getProvider(), $contractAbi);
$params = [ $account ];
$result = $contract->at($contractAddress)->call('balanceOf', $params);
```

But this error is displayed for the last line:

```
Error: The last param must be callback function.
```

Although this is not mentioned in the documents, I changed the source to:

```
$result = $contract->at($contractAddress)->call('balanceOf', $params, function($error,$result){
        ...
    });
```

But it says:

```
Error: Please make sure you have put all function params and callback
```

Note that there is not enough help document for Web3.php.

How can I call the `balanceOf` method of an ERC20 contract?